Why is input only marked as volatile in c++ but volatile const in c
I am working on a C++ application for an arm cortex-m4 MCU. The core_cm4.h header file contains macros to mark registers as input and output. All of them make sense except for the input.
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define __I volatile /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions                 */
#else
#define __I volatile const /*!< Defines 'read only' permissions                 */
#endif
#define __O volatile /*!< Defines 'write only' permissions                */
#define __IO volatile /*!< Defines 'read / write' permissions              */

I do not understand why __I is just volatile in c++. volatile const makes sense as it is a read-only input, but c++ makes it seem like an output.
I am not amazing at c++ so there could be something I just don't know.
Anyone have an idea?
